# DockerPush Fails from Jenkins to Jfrog Docker Registry

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

We have a docker image say xyz:latest which needs to be pushed to my docker registry xxx.com at repo "docker-local" via Jenkins Pipeline

Things were working fine earlier but after updating the artifactory plugins over Jenkins, we are facing the issue with

```
"INFO: The search failed with "Failed to retrieve repository configuration 'docker-local': HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request"."
```

With reference to the code given at (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Setting+Up+Docker+Build-info), more particularly the step 3 part of it, can someone please explain out what does it exactly mean??

```
// Step 3: Push the image to Artifactory.
// Make sure that <artifactoryDockerRegistry> is configured to reference <targetRepo> Artifactory repository. In cas
    def buildInfo = rtDocker.push '<artifactoryDockerRegistry>/hello-world:latest', '<targetRepo>'.
```

What my values currently for them are:

```
artifactoryDockerRegistry: "xxx.com/docker-local/xyz:latest"
targetRepo: "docker-local"
```

Somehow I land-up with the error as mentioned in the comments section of Step3 above.

Can someone please help me with a generic example as to what should the values be??

Comment: Is the `rtDocker` object correctly initialized from the `Artifactory.docker` class member method?

Comment: Which Jenkins Artifactory Plugin version are you using?

Comment: @MattSchuchard: Yes. I have initialized it the same way as mentioned in the offical documentation:

def rtDocker = Artifactory.docker server: server

Comment: @EyalBenMoshe: The latest released version 3.10.3 (https://plugins.jenkins.io/artifactory/#releases)

Comment: Make sure your 'ArtifactoryServerID'  that is been used in your pipeline script, is valid by click on 'Test Connection' button at:
Manage jenkins -> Configure System -> Artifactory servers.
Search for 'ArtifactoryServerID' in the list and press 'Test Connection' on the right. You should see your Artifactory version if everything is ok.

Comment: @Or-G: Yes...I have made sure that the TEST CONNECTION is working fine. I tried to make use of credentialsID option as well rather than specifying the serverID as an alternate but even that isnt working.

Comment: Would you able to share the core pipeline script? is there a proxy on the way from Jenkins to Artifactory?

Comment: The core pipeline script is the same as mentioned in official jfrog link. I have an nginx between my jenkins and artifactory.

Can you please help me understand what Jfrog Documentation Guys are trying to say from the following comment as mentioned on jfrog page:
" // Make sure that <artifactoryDockerRegistry> is configured to reference <targetRepo> Artifactory repository."

Comment: This means to make sure your `<artifactoryDockerRegistry>` is pointing to the same target repository that the second argument is pointing to(`<targetRepo>`). 
For example:
rtDocker.push `{server-name}.jfrog.io/{repo-name}/<image name>`, '{repo-name}'
will push the docker image to `repo-name` repository in Artifactory.
Now, your error occurs after the image was pushed, it tries to collect the build-info from `docker-local` repository by sending GET request to `Artifactory-URL/api/repositories/docker-local` and fails

Comment: @Or-G: Correct. I am able to push the docker image to my artifactory but not able to get back the manifest.json file. My docker-artifactory is behind an nginx server and I have made the necessary changes in the "docker" repo. specifying the necessary nginx related changes still the issue persists. The recent error that I am facing is "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request". Any clue about that??

Comment: @genius_monkey, try to follow [this](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Getting+Started+with+Artifactory+as+a+Docker+Registry) guide on how to setup Nginx with docker registry.
Next, try to validate your setup by running one of jfrog's [project-examples](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/tree/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples) or in your case [Jenkins-scripted-examples-docker-push](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/scripted-examples/docker-push-example/Jenkinsfile)

Comment: @Or-G: I have created the nginx page from artifactory and set it up at the very beignning itself for "docker-local". Also the API mechanism for ping "curl -I -k -v https://<artifactory url>/api/system/ping" is also working fine for me yet the issue persists. Alas I have given up upon jfrog and using the traditional "docker push..." for my pipeline step.